# Equivalent to R in iOS

Tags: iphone, android, ios, resources

In android we have the R class that stands for Resources, where we have references to all of our resources and we can easily access them in the code. Is there an equivalent in iOS? I have this doubt because, I want to be able to define multiple files with different values, for instance:

- DefaultValuesForViewController1
- DefaultValuesForViewController2

Besides creating plist, is there another way (faster and easier like R)?

Comment: Note that I have remove the [tag:r]-tag, since this refers the R programming language

Comment: You are right Andrie, thanks. (Y)

Comment: Are you using IB?  Have you created your views with .xibs?

Comment: At the moment no, but I know I need IBOutlets to every UIView that needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no R class equivalent access method.

In Android, the R class represents access to resources that are consolidated into a native format. iPhone does not do this. Instead, resource files are just copied as is into the application bundle and must be found & opened as such.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "consolidated into a native format"?

Comment: The XML files are compiled into binaries such that R.java is the reference to these resources.  The XML by itself is fairly inefficient, so Android compiles them so the device does not have to.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class to store all of your data for the app. iOS generally likes the app to run lean and mean, so only storing your objects for as long as you need them, releasing them as soon as you are done with them. If you were to store everything globally, it would add some overhead, but assuming you don't have a ton of information, it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent for this in iOS apps. All you get is files that you can enumerate using standard file I/O.

However, you can emulate it partially. [Here's a simple demo on GitHub](http://github.com/catnapgames/TestCppLinkResources)

Answer (score 0):

You can find that [SwiftGen](https://github.com/SwiftGen/SwiftGen)(e.g. Tuist used it) can be used as an alternative for autogenerated R.java file on Android

Two point

- it is third party source
- you have to manually run script after changing your resources