# store all string into a file

Tags: android, ios, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent to R in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082336/equivalent-to-r-in-ios)

I'm looking for something similar to the "string.xml" file in android for iphone programming.

In android, I store all strings into this file and use them by using the following code:

```
getString(R.string.make)
```

Does it exist in objective-c?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to write your methods in such a way that behaves the same way..

Comment: @J03L - This is not an android question. Also, please don't edit duplicates just to get some rep. The edit review queue is long enough without them. Quoting from the [site guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) :"try to make the post significantly better when you edit" I'm sure you know the difference between valuable edits and "ridiculous" edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getString and R files are part of the Android framework (not the Java language), and no, the Objective-C language does not have it either.

However, the iOS (framework) provides `NSLocalizedString` that is somewhat similar in that it allows you to have multiple versions of the string for localization purposes.

See [String Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html) for details.

Comment: I've already known the same issue doen't exists, I needed something similar, NSLocalizedString is just what I was looking for!